# Is there a way to use `ClassMap` to map one document property to multiple class properties?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have a mongo document that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

Now let's say my model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to map one property from the document to two properties in the model?

I tried a `ClassMap` like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.FirstName).SetElementName("name").SetSerializer(new FirstNameSerializer());
    cm.MapMember(c => c.LastName).SetElementName("name").SetSerializer(new LastNameSerializer());
}
```

But I got an error:

> "The property 'LastName' of type 'Person' cannot use element name because it is already being used by property 'FirstName'."

Is there a way to allow this with `ClassMap`?

Comment: no AFAIK, you should create a new custom serializer for Person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible, but if you can add properties to your model, then [Alexandra Petrova's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71847981/996314) might work for you.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to just mark Alexandra Petrova's answer as accepted.

Comment: @JeremyCaney No, I didn't use her solution because I can't add properties to the model. I didn't think to mention that constraint because I didn't consider her solution, but I still think it's a good answer which is why I upvoted it and mentioned it. As @dododo said, it doesn't look like it can be done using only `ClassMap`, which is what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the two properties as read-only and compute their value from the `name` property.

```cs
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string FirstName => Name.Split(" ").First();

     public string LastName => Name.Split(" ").Last();
}
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/bson/mapping/) (Opt-in section)

> A majority of classes will have their members mapped automatically. There are some circumstances where this does not happen. For instance, if your property is read-only, it will not get included in the automapping of a class by default.

By taking this approach, you don't need to write custom serializers, and those two additional properties won't be mapped in the document by default, so no need to add additional class map rules.

Also, in case you don't want to allow changes of the `Name` property, you can create a constructor for the model and mark the set as `private`.

```cs
public class User
{
    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string FirstName => Name.Split(" ").First();

    public string LastName => Name.Split(" ").Last();
}
```